# Update Row by Row

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I want to update row by row but evaluate the context again for each row after updating the current row.

Example:

```
ID   Type       Count   Lag     Lead      FirstNotZero  Calculate (CASE)
 1   Ad-Aware   438584  438541  438602    438584        438584  
 2   Ad-Aware   438602  438584  0         438602        438602  
 3   Ad-Aware   0       438602  0         438602        438602
 4   Ad-Aware   0       0       0         438602        438602      
 5   Ad-Aware   0       0       0         438602        438602      
 6   Ad-Aware   0       0       438746    438602        438602      
 7   Ad-Aware   438746  0       438782    438746        438746  
 8   Ad-Aware   438782  438746  438806    438782        438782
```

I want to replace all `0` values with calculated value. That should be computed with this logic:

```
CASE
WHEN Count = 0 AND Lag != 0 AND Lead != 0 THEN ( Lag + Lead ) / 2
ELSE FirstNotZero
END
```

So when `Count = 0 and Lag and Lead values are known`, average of Lag and Lead should be calculated.

What I want need to do now is to get one row, evaluate the calculation and update where appropriate, therefore update row-by-row.

The problem here is with row with ID 6. As soon as row 5 would be calculated, the Lag for row 6 would be known. Therefore the result of calculate should be `483674` [ ( 438602 + 438746 ) / 2 ] and not `438602` as it is now.

How to perform such update with row-by-row logic? Maybe with `CURSOR UPDATE`?

Comment: Have you tried it through Cursor? if next row calculation depends on previous row's calculated value, then I think Cursor is the only option.

Comment: For 6th row shouldn't it be 438602  + 438746  / 2 and not 438602 + 438782  / 2 ?

Comment: You give the logic for how to compute a replacement value, but so far as I can see, there's no row we can apply it to in your example - *every* row that has a `0` count value also has at least one of `Lag` or `Lead` also equal to `0`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, he goes from top to bottom, and when he is on 6th row 5yh row is filled with 438602

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: you are right, I looked at wrong row. Calculation updated in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know the next row count and the first previous row that is not equal to 0 and use those to calculate.Probably you will want to use `OUTER APPLY` and some `ISNULL` check over `lag` and `lead` like `ISNULL(lag, 0) + ISNULL(lead, 0)` in case you have first or last rows with zero count.:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Count INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 438584 ),
        ( 2, 438602 ),
        ( 3, 0 ),
        ( 4, 0 ),
        ( 5, 0 ),
        ( 6, 0 ),
        ( 7, 438746 ),
        ( 8, 438782 );


WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t t
                        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                count AS lag
                                      FROM      @t
                                      WHERE     count <> 0
                                                AND id <= t.id
                                      ORDER BY  id DESC
                                    ) ca
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        LEAD(lag) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS lead
               FROM     cte1
             )
    UPDATE  cte2
    SET     count = ( lag + lead ) / 2
    WHERE   count = 0

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
1   438584
2   438602
3   438602
4   438602
5   438602
6   438674
7   438746
8   438782
```

Comment: Thanks for it. It would be good except the rows 3-5 as it returns too low values. The number should have growing trend from lowest (row 1) to highest (row 8).

Comment: But for row 3 it is `(438602  + 0) / 2 = 219301`, no?

Comment: As there is Lead = 0 therefore it is replaced with FirstNotZero. See the case in my question.

Comment: See now. I have added the second cte to calculate lead value.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be OK. I can learn something from your script now :).

Comment: @DNac - are you, in fact, wanting us to *interpolate* when there are multiple missing values in a row?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri one last question - would you have any website resource that would help me to understand the WHERE clause within the CROSS APPLY subquery? Especially how does "AND id <= t.id" work exactly here.

Comment: This is aliitle bit hard to explain in this format. Please google some examples like https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Comment: CROSS APPLY itself is fine, just the where clause within the subquery is not clear to me .. that id is lower or equal to id .. but I suppose this is not described by any keyword? Dont know how to google this for.

Comment: @DNac, with that I am selecting the very first row above that is not zero